# How to get the value of for each loop and use it in route query parameters using laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have this problem wherein I have a table from foreach loop like example below and try to pass it on a url path href="{{ url('grade/semester/schoolyear')}}"

| SEMESTER | SCHOOL YEAR | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | 2020-2021 | View |
| 2nd | 2019-2020 | View |
| 1st | 2018-2019 | View |
| 2nd | 2018-2019 | View |

Blade Code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th scope="col" style="color:#1a0dab">Semester</th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:#1a0dab">Academic Year</th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:#1a0dab">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($years as $year)
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">{{ $year->sem}}</td>
            <td>{{ $year->sy}} </td>
            <td>
                <a title="View Grade" **href="{{ url('/grade/{{$year->sem}}/{{$year->sy}}')}}"**>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a title="Print Grade" href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-print"></i>
                </a>
            </td>        
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to get is the correct route: http://127.0.0.1:8000/grade/1st/2018-2019 when I click the link View of the row number 3 in my table so that it will give me the correct path.

Thank you very much for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot evaluate the template multiple times, what you can do is to concatenate the string in order to obtain the url you want:

```
{{ url('/grade/' . $year->sem . '/' . $year->sy) }}
```

where `.` is the PHP operator for string concatenation

Comment: Yes, I try concatenation before you gave the correct answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `web.php` define your route as

```
Route::get('/grade/{sem}/{sy}')->name('grades');
```

In blade you can then access this route via its name and add parameters:

```
<a href="{{ route('grades', ['sem' => $year->sem, 'sy' => $year->sy]) }}">LinkTitle</a>
```

`grades` in `route('grades'...` is the name given.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes